# Fitbit oAuth using PHP cURL - request token returns blank screen

Tags: php, curl, oauth, fitbit

I am trying to get issue a cURL request for "request token" method using Fitbit API. Problem is it does not show anything but a blank screen. However this process is suppose to give me an "access token" which I can use to generate a login URL to authenticate users and give access to my app.

I know there is oAuth php class for this but my server doesn't support oAuth so got to use cURL only. Please help! Many thanks in advance.

```
<?php
define('FITBIT_KEY', '<consumer key from fitbit website>');
define('FITBIT_SECRET', '<consumer secret from fitbit website>');

function buildBaseString($baseURI, $method, $params)
{
    $r = array(); 
    ksort($params); 
    foreach($params as $key=>$value){
        $r[] = "$key=" . rawurlencode($value); 
    }            

    return $method."&" . rawurlencode($baseURI) . '&' . rawurlencode(implode('&', $r)); //return complete base string
}

function buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth)
{
    $r = 'Authorization: OAuth ';
    $values = array();
    foreach($oauth as $key=>$value)
        $values[] = "$key=\"" . rawurlencode($value) . "\""; 

    $r .= implode(', ', $values); 
    return $r; 
}

$url = "http://api.fitbit.com/oauth/request_token";

$oauth = array( 'oauth_consumer_key' => FITBIT_KEY,
                'oauth_consumer_secret' => FITBIT_SECRET,
                'oauth_nonce' => time(),
                'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
                'oauth_timestamp' => time(),
                'oauth_version' => '1.0',
                'oauth_callback' => 'http://h1.servy.net/zerocuisine/index.php');
$base_info = buildBaseString($url, 'GET', $oauth);
$composite_key = rawurlencode(FITBIT_SECRET) . '&';
$oauth_signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base_info, $composite_key, true));
$oauth['oauth_signature'] = $oauth_signature;

$header = array(buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth), 'Expect:');
$options = array( CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
                  CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
                  CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false);

$feed = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($feed, $options);
$json = curl_exec($feed);
curl_close($feed);

$fitbit_data = json_decode($json);

echo '<pre>'.print_r($fitbit_data,true).'</pre>'; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's two problems here which lead to a blank screen. You used **http** instead of **https** in your $url. **https** is required for fitbit token request. You're also running json_decode on a string that's not a json array. The data inside $json is a string from http body response.

Here's my run down in detail to make it fully working below.

Instead of:

```
$url = "http://api.fitbit.com/oauth/request_token";
```

Use:

```
$url = "https://api.fitbit.com/oauth/request_token";
```

Also remove:

```
$fitbit_data = json_decode($json);
```

Change:

```
echo '<pre>'.print_r($json,true).'</pre>'; ?>
```

To:

```
echo '<pre>'. $json .'</pre>'; ?>
```

This will leave you with the successful response of:

```
<pre>oauth_token=93bf6ded129fcfa2b687ce6e625477af&oauth_token_secret=c9cc547ca6dd484f73763e23b0987121&oauth_callback_confirmed=true</pre>
```

shown into your browser.

P.S. make sure to remake this to Oauth 2.0. OAuth 1.0a support will be removed from the Fitbit Web API on April 12, 2016.